# Constant Current/Constant Voltage Cycling of Li-Ion Battery w/ Arduino

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, arduino-uno, electronic-load, battery-monitor

I would like to build a basic cycling controller for charging and discharging small Li-ion coin cells, and plot the voltage curve.

As recommended for LiFePO4, there is a Constant Current Charge and when the voltage reaches the maximum rated voltage, the current would taper off (a CC/CV protocol). Then, the discharge can be done with constant current.

I would like to use an arduino to monitor and control such a protocol, but before doing that, I would like to know how to build the circuit.

For charging, I have a power supply that can deliver 12 VDC. I can control the voltage for that, but is it possible to control the current that goes to the cell with an Arduino? And if so, what controls the current? I read in this group that MOSFETs are an option. Is that accurate?

Also, how to control the Constant Voltage or the tapering voltage after the maximum voltage is reached? What electronic components do I need to use?

And what about the discharge? I can add a resistance and that’ll discharge the battery, but how do I actually control the current? What extra component do I need for that?

What I am trying to ask is: **What electronic components do I need to build a CC/CV Charging/Discharging controller for a Li-ion battery, if I already have a 12 VDC power supply?**

I can read about them, but at this point I don’t even know what to search for, for this type of system, so any advice on what to add for such a controller would be great. It could also be keywords. I can read about them.

Comment: If you split the problem in two separate things, charging and discharging, you’ll probably find plenty of options. Find one of each which solves your problem and combine them.

Answer (score 1):

A year ago I needed something similar. This was my ad hoc solution from components I had at hand. The current regulation loop was implemented in software, but a charging or discharging process needs no fast responding regulator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFLbL5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1. Current measurement is derived from the voltage across the shunt pair R1 R2 and amplified by the differential amplifier OA2. During discharge this voltage is negative, so I added an offset derived from 3.3 V, a 2:1 divider (R5/R6) and buffered by OA1. Analog input A1 reads the battery current. The offset value for zero current (= 1.65 V) must be read before any charge or discharge is enabled.
2. The cell voltage can be read with analog input A2. A voltage divider 2:1 (R3, R4) scales this down to fit in the ADC range using 3.3V as reference. During charge or discharge the voltage across the shunt must be subtracted.
3. The discharge path uses BD677 as load. The software creates a PWM signal at output D11. This is converted and scaled down to an analog DC voltage by R16, R15 and C2. OA4 is a buffer to drive the load transistor.
4. The charge path uses BDW94C as PWM controlled current source. This PMW signal at output D3 must be inverted, because the current increases with falling PWM values. R13 pulls D3 high until the software has established PWM control.

This was designed for charge and discharge currents of 2 A, the transistors need proper cooling to dissipate 7W. This current is too high for a coin cell, so you should use a higher shunt resistor value to match the requirements. If you want to use a 12 V supply, a step down converter is needed. Charging a coin cell from 12 V is not very efficient.

The software control loop reads the cell current and adjusts the PWM to reach the target current. The charge is proportional to the time the loop is running.

It is important to use a rail to rail input and output OpAmp here.

For LiFePO4 cells I discharge down to 2.9 V and charge up to 3.55 V for a full cycle.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try and come back.